# Nullable Enum Dropdown list doesn't work as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a model which contains a nullable enum like so:

```
public class UserSearch : GenericSearch
{
    [Display(Name="User Status", Description = "Filter results by user status")]
    public UserStatus? UserStatus { get; set; } = new UserStatus();
}

public enum UserStatus
{
    Active,
    Inactive,
    Locked
}
```

I request the editor template for the model like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserStatus)
```

My 'Enum.cshtml' template is as follows:

```
@model Enum
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model" class="m-b-none d-block"></label>
    <help-text asp-for="@Model"></help-text>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select asp-for="@Model" asp-items="@new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()))" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Please select an option</option>
        </select>
        <partial name="_ValidationIcon" />
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model" class="validation-message"></span>
</div>
```

This renders like this:
[image]

Problems:

- The drop down defaults to the first enum option, where I would rather it defaulted to my placeholder option. When I tried adding *selected="selected"* to my placeholder option the Enum option, the 'Active' enum option was still selected.
- The label or my help text span does not render?

If I make my *UserStatus* non-nullable, the label then does render:

[image]

e.g.

```
public class UserSearch : GenericSearch
{
    [Display(Name = "User Status", Description = "Filter results by user status")]
    public UserStatus UserStatus { get; set; } = new UserStatus();
}
```

Why is this?

By comparison, in an older MVC5 project, I had the following which worked regardless of whether the Enum was nullable or not:

```
@model Enum
@Html.LabelFor(m => m, new { @class = "m-b-none" })
@Html.DescriptionFor(m => m)
<div class="input-group">
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Helpers.ValidationIcon()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m, null, new { @class = "validation-message" })
</div>
```

I tried switching to use @Html.LabelFor instead of the label tag helper but got the same result.

Comment: I haven't looked into problem #2, but I expect problem #1 is because `= new UserStatus()` is essentially the same as `= UserStatus.Active`.

Comment: I thought that, but I removed "= new UserStatus()" and found that the default selected option is still the 'Active' option.

Comment: Did you do that when the enum was nullable or non-nullable?

Comment: Both. Default option remains as 'Active' either way.